# AJAX is not a function error in d3/flask interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, d3.js

I am a newbie in JavaScript/AJAX world.
I have this d3 function as follows

```
var node = g.selectAll(".node")
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) { 
    return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); 
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; 
  })
  .on("click", function(d){
    console.log(d.ancestors());
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://0.0.0.0:9035/send_data",
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 
        param0:'hi there!', 
        param1:'blah blah', 
        param2:'we get it', 
        param4:d.ancestors() 
      }
    });       
  });
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is send d.ancestors() when user click a d3 node to flask backend (at `http://0.0.0.0:9035/send_data`)

But I am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
```

I am not familiar with ajax and javascript actually.. 
Just trying to "hack" this d3 example
https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/e36d4af364642a70818987941aa192c8/c75e620e662a6899d8df34c287fc5ea00d049513
Thanks

Edit:
Have these libraries in head

I have these libraries in head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: did you added `jquery`?

Comment: @BearBrown Yes, i did.. I have this in the head tag
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a $(document).ready() function?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, jQuery is loaded, before your code is executed, so add the script-tag with jQuery to the head, and wrap your code in a `$(function() { /*your code*/ });`

Comment: I think I have the required libraries.. updated the question with edit?